# How to add a character in front of each word in a sentence till it reaches the length of maximum sized word in the sentence?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, type-conversion, typeerror

I tried to iterate over each word in the sentence after making a list of the sentence words and add 'l' until the length of character in each word reached the length of the maximum sized word. but using while loop, it says that object has no length.

```
def convert_string(ip):
    ip_list = ip.split()
    print(ip_list)
    max_length = max(len(w) for w in ip_list)
    for w in range(len(ip_list)):
        while(len(w) < max_length):
            print(w)
            w = 'l'+w
    return str(ip)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the statement `for w in range(len(ip_list)):`.  w in this case is an integer value, and in the next line you attempt to find the len(w), which throws an error. To fix your problem, replace the statement `for w in range(len(ip_list)):` with `for w in ip_list:`.

Building on [@goodeejay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8323650/goodeejay)'s answer and my previous answer, this is how to solve your problem.

```
sentence = 'Now is the time for all good country men to come to the aide of their country'
def convert_string(ip):
    ip_list = ip.split()
    rslt = []
    max_length = max(len(w) for w in ip_list)
    for w in ip_list:
        rslt.append(w.rjust(max_length, '1'))
    return ' '.join(rslt)  

convert_string(sentence)
```

Yields:

```
'1111Now 11111is 1111the 111time 1111for 1111all 111good country 1111men 11111to 111come 11111to 1111the 111aide 11111of 11their country'
```

Comment: There is no error but the output didn't change

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in `rjust` and `ljust` methods of `str` type used to pad a string with the specified fill character

**Example:**

```py
string = "192.168.0.1"
new_str = string.rjust(20, "l")
```

**Output:**

```
lllllllll192.168.0.1
```